# Web-Scraping using Beautifulsoup and collect table text values

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have my code as below which collect data from NSE website.
Basically I want to collect 2 informations:

> 1. What is the `Announcement` Subject
> 2. Check whether any `pdf` file is available then print the link.
>
> I am able to get the pdf link but unable to read the `Announcement` subject which is
>
> **MIC Electronics Limited has informed the Exchange regarding
>   'Resolution Plan of M/s. Cosyn Consortium in the matter of M/s. MIC
>   Electronics Limited has been approved by Hon'ble NCLT, Hyderabad Bench**

Any help.

```
import requests
import json
import bs4

base_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com'
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/directLink/latestAnnouncementsCorpHome.jsp'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
jsonStr = response.text.strip()
keys_needing_quotes = ['company:','date:','desc:','link:','symbol:']

for key in keys_needing_quotes:
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(key, '"%s":' %(key[:-1]))

data = json.loads(jsonStr)
data = data['rows']
# print(data)

symbol_list = ['MIC']
for x in range(0, len(data)):
    if data[x]['symbol'] in symbol_list:
        response = requests.get(base_url + data[x]['link'], headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)

        try:
            pdf_file = base_url + soup.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
            print("File_Link:", pdf_file)
        except:
            print('PDF not found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your code does not contain anything to even try to get the `Announcement` cell. Adding it is easy enough, check below.

```
symbol_list = ['MIC']
for x in range(0, len(data)):
    if data[x]['symbol'] in symbol_list:
        response = requests.get(base_url + data[x]['link'], headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        try:
            # Announcement is 6th element of class t1.
            announce = soup.find_all(class_='t1')[5].get_text()
            print("Announcement: ", announce)
        except:
            print("Announcement not found")

        try:
            pdf_file = base_url + soup.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
            print("File_Link: ", pdf_file)
        except:
            print('PDF not found')
```

This outputs the intended result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or you can use:

```
for s in soup.find_all('td', 'tablehead'):
    if 'Announcement' in s.text:
        break

print(s.find_next_sibling().text))
# output: 
# MIC Electronics Limited has informed the Exchange regarding 'Resolution Plan of M/s. Cosyn Consortium in the matter of M/s. MIC Electronics Limited has been approved by Hon'ble NCLT, Hyderabad Bench
```